# Possible differents picto for "in meeting" and "in communication" in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

The pictogram for the 2 status ("in communication" and "in meeting") are the same (red circles). Is there a way to easy make the distinction without hovering them ?

[image: "En communication" pictogram]

[image: "En réunion" (meeting) pictogram]

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is. The colour scheme appears to be a red circle with no icon for Busy/In a Meeting. A red circle with a `-` signifies the other person is on Do Not Disturb, or is Presenting. You can't alter the colours or icons for these status icons.

Comment: Sad. Is there a way to say that to Microsoft ?

Comment: Yes, you can raise a ticket on https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/, or upvote an existing suggestion if it already exists.